# What does the impression and ctr means in google webmaster

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am checking google webmaster tools. I entered the search queries section. There i found alot keywords and their impression and ctr etc. I clicked on one of the query keyword there it shows the keyword and position in search result, but when i go to google.com and type the specified keyword it shows no impressions too...

how do i measure find my site's impression on google.com

my site: http://www.trekkingandtoursnepal.com
keyword: trekking nepal

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it shows no impressions too". Do you mean that your site doesn't come up in the results when you put those keywords in?

Comment: yeah it doesn't come up in search result but it shows impression on  google webmaster tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CTR: Click Through Ratio
Impressions: The amount of times it is displayed

So lets say you have a webpage. Then Google can show your page in its SERP's (using the snippet they have created). The amount of times it is shown to the Google visitors is called: Impressions.

When Google users click your snippet (from the search engine results) they "click through" to your website, thus: click though ratio, being the percentage of users that are presented with your snippet and that actually click it.

Comment: Why and when does google create SERP